# Sinon cannot verify if internal function is called once

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai, sinon

given two functions:

```
export const func1 = (accessKeyId, secretAccessKeyID, region, queue, body) =>
  new AWS.SQS({ accessKeyId, secretAccessKey: secretAccessKeyID, region })
    .sendMessage({ QueueUrl: queue, MessageBody: body })
    .promise();

export const func2 = (queue, body) => func1(config.key, config.secret, config.region, queue, body);
```

straight forward functions. How I want to test func2, and verify if func1 i called once with correct param, so I have:

```
import { func1, func2 } from '../uploads';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describ('test 1', ()=> {
it('send job queue should send correct param to sendToSqs', async done => {
    const spy = sinon.spy(func2);
    const queue = 'test-queue';
    const topic = 'test-topic';
    const data = { field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2' };

    await func1(queue, topic, data);
    expect(spy.calledOnce).to.be.equal(true);
    done();
  });
});
```

Running above gives error:

```
(node:29076) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `test-queue'. This service may not be available in the `us-east-1' region.
```

So apparently, even the spy is created, it still tries to call the function inside it. So I think I have two problems here:
1. The `spy` seems not connected to the `func2`, what did I miss?
2. I should probably mock `func1` too. But mock only works for functions inside an object. How do I just mock a function without parent object?

Answer (score 1):

You can't stub/spy on a standalone function. And, the `func1` called inside `func2` will always be original `func1`, not stubbed version. You need to do a few changes:

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const config = {
  key: 'key',
  secret: 'secret',
  region: 'region',
};

export const func1 = (accessKeyId, secretAccessKeyID, region, queue, body) =>
  new AWS.SQS({ accessKeyId, secretAccessKey: secretAccessKeyID, region })
    .sendMessage({ QueueUrl: queue, MessageBody: body })
    .promise();

export const func2 = (queue, body) => exports.func1(config.key, config.secret, config.region, queue, body);
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import * as funcs from './';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('61964269', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const spy = sinon.stub(funcs, 'func1');
    const queue = 'test-queue';
    const topic = 'test-topic';
    const data = { field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2' };

    await funcs.func2(queue, data);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(spy, 'key', 'secret', 'region', 'test-queue', {
      field1: 'value1',
      field2: 'value2',
    });
  });
});
```

We use `exports.func1`, and `import * as funcs from './'`, so that the `func1` will be kept in an object - `module.exports` object. Then, we can stub `func1` in our test files and it will be called when we call `func2`.

The outcome for the unit test:

```sh
  61964269
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (11ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   83.33 |      100 |      50 |      80 |                   
 index.ts |   83.33 |      100 |      50 |      80 | 10                
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```